# Create a program to run it on openWRT getting started

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I just cant find anyone to help me

I have a C++ program and am running it on windows now i want to run it on(Linux) OpenWRT and on raspberry pi raspbian with the use of the opencv
now I installed code blocks I need to know the extension of program I write to be working  openWRT and Raspbian 
what to install on both to run the code and if there any tutorials to help me start
note its the first time to be using C++ ,openWRT and opencv

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about. Perhaps adding some periods could be a good start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to get your program run under desktop Linux like Debian/Ubuntu etc. Then you can try Raspbian. If you take the same Debian distribution version as Raspbian, you can download the toolchain via [Emdebian](https://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain). See `xapt` usage.

If everything is working you should see, if OpenWrt provides OpenCV or look for tutorials about how to install it on OpenWrt. Your software should be converted to OpenWrt package to ease the integration.

I suppose your are using CMake for your project.